# Nodejs User security

Tags: node.js, security, dns, intranet

I want to check if the user accessing the web page is part of a domain.

How can I do this with nodesjs?

Pseudo code like this:

```
  Server.on(request){
       if(getDomainOf(user) === 'thisdomain.local')  // User is a member of the domain
            // Handle request
       else
            // show error (Access denied)
   }
```

Comment: Users aren't members of domains, at least not in the DNS sense. Are you asking if the request came from an ip address that reverse DNS resolves to a particular domain? Or do you mean domain in some other sense? Such as Windows network authentication?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is what I am asking. Should I use the DNS module to do a reverse lookup?  I only want users who are a members of the local windows domain to be able to access the site. I think in a sense it would be Windows network authentication.